# What are the best practice to add several onclick actions on same div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do understand that its an obtrusive way but what am implementing has come a long way so i can't really change at this moment, the method am using works sometimes, others it only acts on the last onclick action, i would like a mode which works without failure, please reference before code to see how i'm adding the onclick actions. I want to know why it works at times and fails to execute all at other times

```
<button onclick="myfunctionone(); myfunctiontwo(); myfunctionthree();">click here</button>
```

Comment: It will only succeed/fail to execute all 3 based on some conditions within the functions, so we can't help you with that. You would need to trace through your code to see what's happening. If you get results you can't understand, update the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Usage of inline event listeners like you do is generally regarded as a *very bad and potentially malicious practice*.

Example:

```js
// make sure the DOM is parsed before trying to find elements to attach listeners
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // find the element to attach the listeners to
  const btn = document.getElementById('example-button');
  // create an array with references of your handlers
  const handlers = [handler1, handler2, handler3];
  // for each handler in that array, add is as a listener to the element
  for (const handler of handlers) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', handler);
  }
});

function handler1(event) {
  console.log('handler 1 says: ' + event.target.textContent);
}

function handler2(event) {
  console.log('handler 2 says: ' + event.target.tagName);
}

function handler3(event) {
  console.log('handler 3 says: ' + event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="example-button">Example button, click me</button>
```

This also allows to remove any one or several of those listeners whenever needed:

```js
// make sure the DOM is parsed before trying to find elements to attach listeners
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('example-button');
  for (const checkbox of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id^=handler]')) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      const handler = window[this.id.replace('toggle', '')];
      btn[`${this.checked ? 'add' : 'remove'}EventListener`]('click', handler);
    })
  }
});

function handler1(event) {
  console.log('handler 1 says: ' + event.target.textContent);
}

function handler2(event) {
  console.log('handler 2 says: ' + event.target.tagName);
}

function handler3(event) {
  console.log('handler 3 says: ' + event.target.id);
}
```

```css
[id^=handler] + label::after { content: 'off'; }
[id^=handler]:checked + label::after { content: 'on'; }
```

```html
<button id="example-button">Example button, click me</button>
<br />
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="handler1toggle" /> <label for="handler1toggle">handler 1 </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="handler2toggle" /> <label for="handler2toggle">handler 2 </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="handler3toggle" /> <label for="handler3toggle">handler 3 </label>
```

Comment: I know that its a very bad habit, thats why i highlighted that its obtrusive, your way seems miles better. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use Jquery and do something like:

```
$("#examle-button").on("click", function(){
    myfunctionone();
    myfunctiontwo();
    myfunctionthree();
})
```

Comment: How would you separately remove one or several of those listener functions then?

Comment: if(condition1){
    myfunctionone()
}


Is that what you mean? @connexo

Comment: Check my answer below for what I mean.